# Usage of pointers in below code

Tags: c++, pointers, coredump

```
1.NODE **ptr = (NODE **)node
NODE  *delPtr = *ptr;
obj->addList(delPtr->strKey);

2.NODE **ptr = (NODE **)node;
obj->addList(*ptr->strKey);
```

I am analysing this for a core dump program I am making and the functionality seems to be same.
What is the difference between these two declarations? Does the second also do a core dump? 
Please help.

Answer (score 6):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says that `->` is evaluated before the dereference operator `*` so

```
obj->addList(*ptr->strKey);
```

is actually

```
obj->addList(*(ptr->strKey));
```

If you want to use this form, you'll need to use brackets around `*ptr`

```
obj->addList((*ptr)->strKey);
```

Comment: Sorry..to be precise the line is obj->_callBack((*ptr)->intKey)..but my question is whether the two form of declarations(1&2) in my question have any difference while execution